# how to open css when I changed the default program

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to create my first web page. The style part of the code was suposed to change the background color, but it dont.

I think the code works so why dont it show up when I use it?

By mistake I changed the default way to open css files to "skype" and this created a problem. I changed it to notepad, but that did not fix the problem and I dont know what should be the  default program to open it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title> My web Page </title>  
    <style>
      body {
      background:red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>   
    <h1>  My webSite</h1>
    <h2> This is my homepage content</h2>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to view the raw .css file in a browser?

Comment: no. This is the HTML file.

Comment: Ok, so how is the portion of how you open the css file relevant (skype, notepad, etc)?

Comment: just right click and open it with your favorite browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is the solution of your problem..[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's the file type of your code?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can right-click a file and click on **Open with...**. Choose any Text-Editor even Editor gets the Job done. I would recommend **Brackets** as an Editor. The choice of your Editor doesnt has an Impact on your Code at all. First: Dont ever put inline-CSS in your HTML or use style Tags like this. Create a style.css file and use this to style your HTML Elements by using their ID or class which you assigned in your HTML-Tags.

Edit:`body {
background-color: red;
}` 
Would be correct.